# os.system with embedded commands

Tags: python, postgresql, operating-system

I've now been struggling a long time and still can't get this line of code working :

```
os.system('su - postgres -c "psql -c \'ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD \\\"{0}\\\";\'"'.format(self.password))
```

and log result :

```
2013-11-12 19:58:42 ICT ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""password"" at character 45
2013-11-12 19:58:42 ICT STATEMENT:  ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD "password";
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Put your command-string into a variable, then print it so it can be checked.  Using a variable instead of coding directly into a call makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Urgh. Please use `psycopg2`, the native Python client driver for PostgreSQL, if at all possible.

If you must shell out to `psql`, use the `subprocess` module's `check_call` function, which is easier and safer as it takes care of quoting for you.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call([
    'psql', '-c',
    'ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD "{0}";'.format(self.password)
])
```

`os.system` should really be a last resort IMO.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I can't use psycopg2 yet as the script is supposed to run before any modules is installed. I wrote this but check_call seems to misinterpret the command as the psql shell remains opened after execution : check_call(['sudo', '-u', postgres', 'sh', '-c', 'psql', '--quiet', '-c', 'ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD "{0}";'.format(self.pgsql_pwd)]) ? And the doc specifies not to use PIPE statement, so how can I work this out ?

Comment: @JohnDoe I accidentally omitted the `-c` from my example. Fixed. If you want sudo, don't wrap the command with an `sh -c`. `check_call(['sudo', '-u', 'postgres', 'psql', '--quiet', '-c', '...sql...'])`. If you use `sh -c` then you get yourself back into the same argument quoting mess you were in already.

Comment: Great it works ! But I had to replace the double quotes by escaped single quotes (\') too as @Jayadevan suggested. Thanks to all ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Password should be in single quotes -

```
postgres=# create user usr with password "password";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""password""
LINE 1: create user usr with password "password";
                                      ^
postgres=# create user usr with password 'password';
CREATE ROLE
```