# Execute psql command from python script

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, subprocess, psql

In what way can I execute a psql command from a Python script? My code inserts and updates data from a PostgreSQL DB (using psycopg2 and cursor method). It works fine when I execute a query like

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE Segment set idcurve = %s where id = %s ", (id_curve, id_segment,))
```

But in the psql case, when I pass commands to `cursor.execute` ([see edits to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427107/usage-rollback-to-savepoint-with-condition/59427165?noredirect=1#comment105041613_59427165)) I get `SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "\"`. 
Moreover, the command fails in console.sql DataGRIP (it executes for all the rows anyway...)

Does this command only work in the shell (do I have to use os.system)? as `cursor` is not able to interpret it?

**EDIT**
trying with subprocess:

```
import subprocess

sql = """SELECT uuid IS NULL AS is_uuid FROM dpoint WHERE uuid = '5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214';
\gset 
\if :is_uuid 
    INSERT INTO DPoint (uuid) VALUES ('5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214');
    WITH ins1 AS (INSERT INTO Point (latitude, longitude, srid) 
          VALUES (64.44, 28.77, 4326) RETURNING id AS id_point)
    INSERT INTO SPoint (idPoint, uuiddpt) VALUES ((SELECT id_point FROM ins1), '5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214');
\endif
"""
subprocess.check_call(['psql -h localhost -d dbase -U myuser -W --command={}'.format(sql)], env={'PGPASSWORD': 'mypass'})
```

Throws `OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long`

**EDIT2**

```
subprocess.check_call(['psql', '-q', '-U', 'myuser', '-h', 'localhost', '-c', '{}'.format(sql), 'dbase'], env={'PGPASSWORD': 'mypass'})
```

When I split up all the arguments the query is trying to execute -> it fails with `syntax error at or near "\"`. `-E` (as Lu M suggests) does not help. It works in the case where I save my query to .sql file however I would like to execute it interactively.

**EDIT3**

According to [psql tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/tutorial-transactions.html) in chapter --command=command there are two options available to mix SQL and psql meta-commands. In what way is it possible to wrap it in a subprocess?
I tried both, but undesired extra backslashes appear and it is not recognized as one command:

```
subprocess.check_call(['psql', '-q', '-U', 'myuser', '-h', 'localhost',
                   '-c', '{}'.format(sql),
                   '-c', '{}'.format('\gset'),
                   '-c', '{}'.format('\if :is_uuid '),
                   '-c', '{}'.format(sql2),
                   '-c', '{}'.format('\endif'), 'dbase'],
                  env={'PGPASSWORD': 'mypass'})
```

fails with `unrecognized value ":is_uuid" for "\if expression": Boolean expected`

Comment: The commands starting with `\` are, as you already guessed, `psql` commands and are not interpreted by the DBMS itself but by the `psql` program.

Comment: @stickybit is this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19930714/8129993 is still valid and up-to-date?

Comment: Well, why don't you just try it and see if it works for you?

Comment: I am trying, but no success (see edits to my question)

Comment: You could theoretically rewrite this to use regular sql, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to do.  The first query would either return nothing or false.

Comment: @Jeremy I tried using clean SQL for this case (see link in my question), I am not able to do it like that( Maybe you have an idea for regular SQL?

Comment: If you try with a sql query more litte and simple like select * from.... work?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar, what do you mean `select * from...`? from where?

Comment: @Jane any query that you want...work?..

Comment: `'-c', '{}'.format(sql)` works if sql variable contains only simple SQL, without `\gset` etc.. This is what you mean? I found here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html in chapter --command=command an example of using mix SQL and psql meta-commands. But still don't know how to wrap it to subprocess

Comment: yes..ok ,..I will try to replicate but also check this check my reply of another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462803/how-can-i-get-the-output-of-a-python-subprocess-command-that-contains-a-pipe/59462840#59462840    ... in variable cmd add your full command psql

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to run a [Meta-Command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) through psycopg2 similar to to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532489/meta-commands-in-psycopg2-d-not-working). Psycopg2 is unable to process Meta-Commands and that's why it's throwing this Syntax error.

What may work for your case is the following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532489/meta-commands-in-psycopg2-d-not-working):

> It's really an important information that the command line psql -E will echo SQL queries used to implement \d and other backslash commands (whenever you use one of them in the psql prompt) as @piro has written in comment. This way you get what you want very easily.

Edit: Otherwise you will have to use subprocess, as comments have already pointed out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am trying your both ideas (see my edits), but no success(

Comment: I’m currently busy, but if the problem persists, I‘ll see if I can find a solution for running meta commands in a subprocess. Maybe try storing the whole command in a txt file and reading that?

Comment: I tried to save my command to .sql file. It works, but I would like to execute it interactively

Comment: It‘s just a hack for now, but you could theoretically always generate the file, then call it via subprocess.

Comment: Serialization/deserialization is a high-load operation, isn't it? There are so many objects I have to process...Moreover I have tested with hard-coded values for uuid, etc. in fact they are parametrized from script (what way is to generate the queries? According to http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters the correct way is to execute sql with passing variables)

Comment: Having decided to use python, you should use python.  Translating the "psql" script into python (over psycopg2) should not be hard.  It will easier than applying bandaid over bandaid over bandaid.